# jQuery using string as jQuery object for DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, string, object, dom

`myVariable` is a string containing HTML.

In order to manipulate it I'm doing following:

```
$(myVariable).find('div.grid-12-12').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('class','grid-2-12');
                        alert($(this).attr('class'));
        });
```

What I see in the alert is always `grid-12-12`.
Do it found the right div, but seems that the change is not saved in `myVariable`.

Can you please help me?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/modifying-html-strings-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$(myVariable)` it creates a DOM element with the contents of `myVariable`, then your `attr` call modifies that element. The original contents of `myVariable` is not affected in any way, since it's just text.

If you want to get back the textual representation of what the operation would produce, you could append it to an empty element and then retrieve its html contents:

```
var newElement = $(myVariable)... // your code
myVariable = $("<p/>").append(newElement).html();
```

or simply (if supported):

```
myVariable = newElement[0].outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clean browser cache. Worked here. Look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Index JQuery Mobile</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#busca').find('div.grid-12-12').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('class', 'grid-2-12');
                    alert($(this).attr('class'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="busca">
        <div class="grid-12-12"></div>
        <div class="grid-12-12"></div>
        <div class="grid-12-12"></div>
        <div class="grid-12-12"></div>
        <div class="grid-12-12"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```